# Having trouble interpreting mail log DNS errors

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, reverse-dns, email-bounces

I have a postfix mail server on Debian. A client of mine just informed me that they were unable to send an email to me and it appears that there is a problem with their mail server. I would like to get back to them with the actual problem, but I'm unable to figure this out. This was in the bounce email:

```
The address to which the message has not yet been delivered is:

eric@mydomain.com
Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT
TO::
host dog.myhostname.com [{server_ip}]: 450 4.7.1
:
Recipient address rejected: SPF-Result=server.thehostingserver.co.uk:
'SERVFAIL' error on DNS 'TXT' lookup of 'server.thehostingserver.co.uk'
```

Checking through the `/var/log/mail.log` file I see the following lines which coincide with the bounce email:

```
Dec  6 10:32:16 dog postfix/smtpd[366]: connect from unknown[37.26.106.210]
Dec  6 10:32:16 dog postfix/smtpd[366]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[37.26.106.210]
Dec  6 10:32:16 dog postfix/smtpd[366]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[37.26.106.210]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Dec  6 10:32:18 dog postfix/policy-spf[421]: Policy action=DEFER_IF_PERMIT SPF-Result=server.thehostingserver.co.uk: 'SERVFAIL' error on DNS 'TXT' lookup of 'server.thehostingserver.co.uk'
Dec  6 10:32:18 dog postfix/smtpd[366]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[37.26.106.210]: 450 4.7.1 <eric@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: SPF-Result=server.thehostingserver.co.uk: 'SERVFAIL' error on DNS 'TXT' lookup of 'server.thehostingserver.co.uk'; from=<info@example.com> to=<eric@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<server.thehostingserver.co.uk>
```

I am having a bit of trouble understanding this.

1) Why does it say "connect from unknown"? This IP clearly resolves to `server.oovavoohosting.co.uk`. (Note, other incoming connections do show up correctly with their hostnames)

```
# nslookup 37.26.106.210
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
210.106.26.37.in-addr.arpa      name = server.oovavoohosting.co.uk.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
106.26.37.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns1.racksrv.com.
106.26.37.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns2.racksrv.com.
ns1.racksrv.com internet address = 37.26.104.214
ns2.racksrv.com internet address = 37.26.105.214
```

2) If the aforementioned IP resolves to `server.oovavoohosting.co.uk`, where does it get the hostname `server.thehostingserver.co.uk` from? I can see this hostname doesn't exist, which is why it's returning a `SERVFAIL`, I just don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The `unknown` in the log means that the reverse name for the IP (`server.oovavoohosting.co.uk`) does not forward resolve to the original IP address.

2) It looks like the remote server introduced itself as `server.thehostingserver.co.uk`. Looking at the log, I see `helo=server.thehostingserver.co.uk`, which I interpret as what the server used in the SMTP greeting.

Why that is used in the SPF test I did not know until I looked it up [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#HELO_tests) and it seems that this is now a mandatory test:

> For an empty Return-Path as used in error messages and other
>   auto-replies, an SPF check of the HELO-identity is mandatory.
>
> With a
>   bogus HELO identity the result NONE would not help, but for valid host
>   names SPF also protects the HELO identity. This SPF feature was always
>   supported as an option for receivers, and later SPF drafts including
>   the final specification recommend to check the HELO always.

In summary, a server connected to your mail server and said

```
HELO server.thehostingserver.co.uk
```

in its greeting. Your server then looked up the SPF record and not finding a DNS entry for this server refused the mail.